# typeorm create new table for each ManyToOne entity

Tags: javascript, postgresql, typescript, typeorm

I have such schema (db is `postgresql`):

```
@Entity('hubs')
export class Hub {

    @PrimaryGeneratedColumn('uuid')
    id: string;

    @Column()
    ip: string;

    @OneToMany(type => HubStatus, statusLog => statusLog.hub, { cascade: true })
    statusLog: Array<HubStatus>;

    @UpdateDateColumn()
    updatedAt: Date;
}

@Entity('hub-status')
export class HubStatus {

    @PrimaryGeneratedColumn()
    id: string;

    @Column({type: 'json')
    somecolumn

    @ManyToOne(type => Hub, hub => hub.statusLog)
    hub: Hub;

    @CreateDateColumn()
    createdAt: Date;
}
```

`hub-status` table could get really big (`2592000` entries per parent object). was wandering if it's possible to create a new table for each `Hub.statusLog` ?(and if it makes sense) the total amount of `Hub` entries will not be higher than 50.